Converting voxels into polygons taking into account the colors
I have code to convert voxels to polygons:
extern class voxel
{
public:
    sf::Vector3f position;
    sf::Vector3f rotation;
    sf::Vector3f attraction_direction;
    sf::Color* color;

    float weight = 0;
};

extern class polygon
{
public:
    sf::Vector3f position[3];
    sf::Color* color;
};

extern class model
{
public:
    voxel* voxels = new voxel[1];
    polygon* polygons = new polygon[1];

    sf::Vector3f center = sf::Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
     
    int voxels_count = 0;
    int polygons_count = 0;

    void set_voxel(int voxel_count, sf::Vector3f voxel_position, sf::Color* voxel_color, sf::Vector3f voxel_rotation, sf::Int16 voxel_weight = 0)
    {
        voxels[voxel_count].position = voxel_position;
        voxels[voxel_count].color = voxel_color;
        voxels[voxel_count].rotation = voxel_rotation;
        voxels[voxel_count].weight = voxel_weight;
        voxels_count++;
    }

    model()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < voxels_count; i++) {
            center += voxels[i].position;
        }
        center /= static_cast<float>(voxels_count);
    };

    ~model()
    {
        delete[] voxels;
        delete[] polygons;
    }

    void optimize()
    {
        polygons_count = 0;
        polygon* polygons__ = new polygon[voxels_count * 12];

        auto add_polygon = [this](const sf::Vector3f& v0, const sf::Vector3f& v1, const sf::Vector3f& v2, sf::Color* color, polygon* polygons_) {
            polygons_[polygons_count].position[0] = v0;
            polygons_[polygons_count].position[1] = v1;
            polygons_[polygons_count].position[2] = v2;
            polygons_[polygons_count].color = color;
            polygons_count++;
            };

        for (int i = 0; i < voxels_count; ++i) {
            if (!is_internal(voxels[i])) {
                sf::Vector3f p = voxels[i].position;
                sf::Vector3f size = sf::Vector3f(1, 1, 1);

                sf::Vector3f corners[8] = {
                    p,
                    p + sf::Vector3f(size.x, 0, 0),
                    p + sf::Vector3f(size.x, size.y, 0),
                    p + sf::Vector3f(0, size.y, 0),
                    p + sf::Vector3f(0, 0, size.z),
                    p + sf::Vector3f(size.x, 0, size.z),
                    p + sf::Vector3f(size.x, size.y, size.z),
                    p + sf::Vector3f(0, size.y, size.z)
                };

                if (is_face_visible(p + sf::Vector3f(1, 0, 0), voxels[i].color)) {
                    add_polygon(corners[1], corners[5], corners[6], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                    add_polygon(corners[1], corners[6], corners[2], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                }
                if (is_face_visible(p + sf::Vector3f(-1, 0, 0), voxels[i].color)) {
                    add_polygon(corners[0], corners[3], corners[7], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                    add_polygon(corners[0], corners[7], corners[4], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                }
                if (is_face_visible(p + sf::Vector3f(0, 1, 0), voxels[i].color)) {
                    add_polygon(corners[3], corners[2], corners[6], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                    add_polygon(corners[3], corners[6], corners[7], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                }
                if (is_face_visible(p + sf::Vector3f(0, -1, 0), voxels[i].color)) {
                    add_polygon(corners[0], corners[4], corners[5], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                    add_polygon(corners[0], corners[5], corners[1], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                }
                if (is_face_visible(p + sf::Vector3f(0, 0, 1), voxels[i].color)) {
                    add_polygon(corners[4], corners[7], corners[6], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                    add_polygon(corners[4], corners[6], corners[5], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                }
                if (is_face_visible(p + sf::Vector3f(0, 0, -1), voxels[i].color)) {
                    add_polygon(corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                    add_polygon(corners[0], corners[2], corners[3], voxels[i].color, polygons__);
                }
            }
        }

        polygons = new polygon[polygons_count];
        for (int k = 0; k < polygons_count; ++k) {
            polygons[k] = polygons__[k];
        }
        delete[] polygons__;
    }

private:
    bool is_internal(const voxel& v)
    {
        int neighbors = 0;
        sf::Vector3f offsets[6] = {
            sf::Vector3f(1, 0, 0), sf::Vector3f(-1, 0, 0),
            sf::Vector3f(0, 1, 0), sf::Vector3f(0, -1, 0),
            sf::Vector3f(0, 0, 1), sf::Vector3f(0, 0, -1)
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            sf::Vector3f neighbor_position = v.position + offsets[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < voxels_count; ++j) {
                if (voxels[j].position == neighbor_position) {
                    neighbors++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return neighbors == 6;
    }

    bool is_face_visible(const sf::Vector3f& neighbor_position, sf::Color* color)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < voxels_count; ++j) {
            if (voxels[j].position == neighbor_position && voxels[j].color == color) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

BUT it doesn't take into account their colors and I don't know how to implement this
And I wrote this code about a year ago and I don't understand what's going on here anymore
